# src in audio-tag with webapi stream getting songname from responsephrase

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I have a page with the html5 audio tag. The src is asking a webapi controller. The controller returns async a stream, which is played in the audio tag.
Now i added the function random and want to show the song title. In the controller I added to the response a responsephrase with the songtitle.
Here the HTML code:

```
<div id="audioControl" class="col-md-6">
  <audio controls autoplay="autoplay" id="player">
    <source id="audioSource" src='/api/Audio/mp3/' type='audio/mp3' />
    not supported
  </audio>
```

and the controller:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse();
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(rndPath[rndIndex]); //path of the mp3 
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.ReasonPhrase = fileInfo.Name;
response.Content = new PushStreamContent
    (audio.WriteToStream, new   MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/mp3"));
return response;
```

With fiedler or the network-tab of my browser I get the the correct name of the mp3.Now I want to set the src of the `src` of the `<source>` tag with a javascript function where I can get the responsephrase with the songtitle.
Any idea how to do that?

Or is the only way to get the name of the mp3 making web-api statefull or using a cookie?

My newest idea is to save the name in a server-session-variable and to fetch the name with another api-call.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
in the controller:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(rndPath[rndIndex]); 
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.ReasonPhrase = fileInfo.Name;
HttpContext.Current.Cache[User.Identity.Name] = fileInfo.Name;

response.Content = new PushStreamContent
  (audio.WriteToStream, new    MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/mp3"));
return response;
```

Guess will not work with 2 browserwindows opened.
Added a ne controller:

```
 public class TitleController : ApiController
      {
        public string Get()
        {
          string title =(string)HttpContext.Current.Cache[User.Identity.Name.ToString()];

      return title;
    }
  }
```

and in the view

```
var aud = document.getElementById("player");
aud.onloadeddata = function ()
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'api/Title/',
          cache: false,
          async: false
        }).success(function (data)
        {
          $("#title").html(data);

    });
};
```